# How do I finish hand-sewing a seam?

Tags: sewing

I'm mending my (second hand) leather gloves by hand.

My sewing skills are rudimentary, but I like fixing the seams of or patching up clothes every now and then.

However, I never know how to finish up a sewn seam. I usually just keep repeating the last stitch, alternating the angle a little bit, or the direction, in a random fashion (random perhaps because I reason that if it's hard for me to unravel, it must be so too for the thread itself).

**I would like to know if there's a proper way to finish sewing a seam.**

[image: Leather gloves in the midst of being mended]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do at this point with your gloves, is to take the needle and slide it under that last stitch (I took a close look at your pic) leaving a loop behind, then take the needle and slide through that loop to create a knot, you may need to do this twice. Then, I usually push the needle into the material and leave extra thread inside the work, cutting what is super extra or bothersome.[image: slide through stitch and through loop pull to knot]
Create the knot
[image: knot close up sometimes twice]
Hide the extra
[image: sink the extra thread into the material]

These stitches shown here are just so I can show a sample, my stitch work is typically better. Though when I darn, I let it get messy. LOL
happy mending sustainability lovers!

Comment: PS I would start with a knot and bring the needle in through the glove.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way (as suggested by WikiHow):

```
1   Flip the fabric over. ...
2   Slide the needle under the nearest stitch and pull it to make a loop. ...
3   Insert the needle through the loop and pull it tightly to make a knot. ...
4   Tie the thread through another loop to double knot the stitch. ...
5   Trim the excess thread and turn your fabric over.
```

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=x5PbLKldLE0
This video offers some alternatives